# Delete image file with PHP

Tags: php, image, file

Below is the code that should delete the image file.
 
I have row that contains (id, name, pic), I can delete this row from database,
but did not delete the image from file.

```
if(isset($_GET["delete"])){
   $pic=$_GET["pic"];
   $qry="delete from section where id=".$_GET["delete"];
   $de = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
   $filetmp = $_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"];
   // $filename = $_FILES["pic"]["name"];
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $qr ="SELECT id FROM section ORDER BY id ASC";
   $res = mysqli_query($conn,$qr);
   $path = "uploads/$id.jpg";
   //move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$path);
   $fpath = "/images_upload/$path";
   unlink("$fpath");
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You also are missing some functions here. Also `did not delete the image from file`, do you mean server, not file?

Comment: @chris85 yes from my server

Answer (score 0):

> $path = "uploads/$id.jpg";

you must assign a value of $id